# Laravel 5.5 abort error when trying to authenticate middleware

Tags: php, laravel

When i try to login into my dashboard, my authentication works well without middleware, but when i apply middleware and try to login to the dashboard i get this.

[image]

Which this is linked to the my authenticate middleware file

Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(! Auth::User()) {
            if ($request->expectsJson()) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated. You are not a User.'], 401);
            }

            abort(403, "You're not a User no permission bro");
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My route is followed by:

```
Route::get('/auth/signup','UserController@getRegister')->name('getRegister');

Route::post('/auth/signup', 'UserController@userRegister')->name('signup');

Route::post('/auth/signin','UserController@userLogin')->name('user.login');


Route::get('/auth/login', 'UserController@getLogin')->name('login');
Route::get('/', 'UserController@getHome')->name('home');
Route::get('/auth/logout', 'UserController@logOut')->name('logout');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'myauth'], function() {

    Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@getDashboard')->name('dashboard');

});
```

Thanks in advance im beginning to think there is a bug because im following the [laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) practices.

Comment: I think your middle ware should have auth as well as myauth.

Comment: like this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'myauth'],(['middleware' => 'myauth', 'auth' ],` ?

Comment: try ['middleware' => ['myauth','auth]]

Comment: @usrNotFound yeah it didn't work

Comment: can you check if you get any user when you do `dd(Auth::user())`

Comment: @usrNotFound you mean `(Auth::user())` without the !  ?

Comment: @usrNotFound when i do it without the !, it works, but the middleware doesn't work, anyone can access the dashboard

Comment: Just want to see if you have access to user object. So in your middleware ‘dd(Auth::user())’. Check if it’s not empty

Comment: @usrNotFound im not sure what you want me to do ? can you please demonstrate dd(auth::user) where ? im confused

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough. In you middleware where you have the check for user I want you to comment the whole check and try dd(Auth::user()). What it does is die and dump user if there is any.

Comment: Do `dd(\Auth::user())` as the first in your middleware.

Comment: @usrNotFound now i understand let me do that

Comment: @usrNotFound i get `null`

Comment: i think that the issue. Can you make sure you have both middleware applied to the route and do exactly the same thing you just did. Again want to check if you can have access to `user` when auth middleware is applied.

Comment: `Route::group(['middleware' => 'myauth'],(['middleware' => 'myauth', 'auth' `], i still get null

Comment: No `Route::group('middleware' => ['myauth','auth']] .....`